# How to plot error bars for a mean with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted my data as a scatter bar plot and have a benchmark (Basemodel) and a theoretical value (AASHTO) that I am presenting with different colored points. I use the following code and my graph looks as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = plotshear, aes(x = Shear, y = LLDF)) + geom_jitter(aes(colour = Source))

# plotshear data:

      Source     Shear        LLDF
# 1   Baseline   EXT.Single   0.7627894
# 2   Samples    EXT.Single   0.7130376
# 3   Baseline   EXT.Multi    0.8521338
# 4   Samples    EXT.Multi    0.7975502
# 5   Baseline   INT.Single   0.5706947
# 6   Samples    INT.Single   0.5462812
# 7   Baseline   INT.Multi    0.7291602
# 8   Samples    INT.Multi    0.7331171
# 9   AASHTO     EXT.Multi    0.8250000
# 10  AASHTO     INT.Single   0.7200000
# 11  AASHTO     INT.Multi    0.8840000
```

I actually need a error bar for a mean looking like this:

current plot

[image: current plot]

plot needed

[image: plot needed]

Comment: Could you supply some example data for plotshear?

Comment: I just edited the question to add the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that reproduces the "plot needed" figure from your data:

```
library(ggplot2)

# plotshear data:
plotshear <- data.frame(Source = c(rep(c("Baseline", "Samples"), 4), rep("AASHTO", 3)),
                        Shear = c(rep("EXT.Single", 2), rep("EXT.Multi", 2), rep("INT.Single", 2),
                                  rep("INT.Multi", 3), "INT.Single", "INT.Multi"),
                        LLDF = c(0.7627894, 0.7130376, 0.8521338, 0.7975502, 0.5706947,
                                 0.5462812, 0.7291602, 0.7331171, 0.8250000, 0.7200000, 0.8840000))

#without error bars
ggplot(data = plotshear, aes(x = Shear, y = LLDF)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Source)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=4) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1)) 

#with error bars
ggplot(data = plotshear, aes(x = Shear, y = LLDF)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Source)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=4) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar")
```

Comment: Thank you, I had two questions. 1) When I add the error bars, it either adds the line to the max or min but I want it for both. 2) I am trying to keep some of the points of the data in the plot. I create a new data frame called "points" with the ones I want to plot and add the following to the ggplot line: geom_jitter(data = points, colour = Source). I keep getting a error.

Comment: @Maral Dorri sorry I don’t understand your first question  - when I plot the error bars I see them on both the top and bottom of the box plots. You should not need to create a new data frame to plot your points, even if they’re a subset of the data. Can you tell me more about which points you want to add to the plot?

Comment: All the points that have the Source column set to "Baseline" or "AASHTO". I want to have a legend saying what color is Baseline and what color is AASHTO

Comment: @Maral Dorri I edited my answer to include jittered points colored by the Source column. If you decide in the future that you need to plot data from a separate dataframe, you will need to add the argument "inherit.aes = FALSE" so that you can override the aesthetics of the previous data. This might be why you were getting an error.